# Selecting specific column value with condition

Tags: yii2

I want to get a specific column from User table in yii2 using active record below is my code

```
$model = User::findOne(['id' => 1]);
```

this will return all  the column from the table with user id equal 1, but suppose i just want to get only username and email from this column how do i write the query with active record, i tried the below code but it wont work..`

```
$model = User::find('username','email')->where('id'=1)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
$model = User::find()
           ->select('column1, column2')
           ->where(['id' => $id])
           ->one();

echo $model->column1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply try:

```
$model = User::find()->select(['username','email'])->where('id=1')->One();
```

**OR**

```
$model = User::find()->select(['username','email'])->where('id=:id', [ ':id' => 1 ])->One();
```

Second way is more preferable.

Answer (score 3):

If you need Model User, try this:

```
$user = User::find()
           ->select('column1, column2')
           ->where(['id' => $id])
           ->one();
```

For getting few columns without Model use this:

```
$columns = User::find()
           ->select('column1, column2')
           ->where(['id' => $id])
           ->asArray()
           ->one();
```

If you need single column without Model, use this:

```
$column = User::find()
           ->select('column1')
           ->where(['id' => $id])
           ->column();
```

OR

```
$column = User::find()
           ->select('column1')
           ->where(['id' => $id])
           ->scalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$model = User::find()
       ->select(['column1', 'column2'])
       ->where(['id' => $id])
       ->one();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below way is correct. but other filed values are returning as NULL.

```
$model = User::find()->select(['username','email'])->where('id=1')->One();
```

The best way is to use the cdbcriteria for the Query.